# Extract and download model to local machine in OTG format

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

According to https://github.com/wallabyway/OTG-client-sample, a new OTG format for the forge viewer has been released and it looks like it has siginificant improvement in performance as opposed to the traditional SVF format.

Currently,we are using model derivative API to translate RVT/NWD files to SVF and download it to our local machine using the extractor from the following link:
https://github.com/cyrillef/extract.autodesk.io

The question is that how do I to translate the model into OTG format and load it locally?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now (end of August 2019), the OTG file format can only be obtained via a manual post-processing step through a series of unofficial API calls. However, we're planning on including the OTG output as part of the standard Model Derivative translation. Stay tuned to the [blog](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog) and [@AutodeskForge](https://twitter.com/autodeskforge) for updates!