# How to extract and download model to local machine in OTG format

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57623561/extract-and-download-model-to-local-machine-in-otg-format), at the end of August of 2019, a new OTG format cannot be extracted and downloaded. 
Is there any updated information? I cannot find any information in the [blog](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to the [forge.commandline-nodejs](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge.commandline-nodejs) sample. It has the option to download the OTG bubble and also shows how to configure the viewer to load it.

Here is an example to get the OTG from a BIM360 item.

```
# Do authorization/authentication.
node forge.js 3legged auto

# Get the list of Hubs.
node forge.js hubs ls

# Get the list of projects.
node forge.js projects ls $hubid

# Get the Project tree information.
node forge.js projects tree $hubid $projectid

# Download the SVF Bubble
node forge.js bubble get $versionid ./bubbles/MyPath --otg

# Create an HTML page with your local URN
node forge.js html get /MyPath/$VERSION_NUMBER/bubble.json ./bubbles/output.html

# Start local server and load the HTML page.
open http://localhost:7124/output.html & PORT=7124 & node fluent-server/start.js ./bubbles/
```

From [README.md](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge.commandline-nodejs/tree/master/fluent-server)

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.

I tried to get the OTG files according to your answer, but I couldn’t.
The errors occurred in “getViewModelJson” function to get “attrs.json” and so on. The error message is the following.

Comment: !!  <<output dir>>\pdb\vals.json
Error: Unauthorized
(node:20424) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: #<otgBubble>
(node:20424) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:20424) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: Hey, just to make sure, you provisioned your BIM360 account with your Forge client ID, and you replaced the $xxx by your hub, project, item, and version IDs? Can you also confirm your are running on Windows.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer, I tried 2-legged OAuth. So not to connect to BIM 360. Can not OTG model be downloaded with 2-legged OAuth?

Comment: @TakumiOYA, if you are using 2legged and OSS, then the OTG format is not generated automatically, hence the error. It also means you would need to call an API to generate the OTG bubble for OSS. Unfortunately, I cannot share that API today since this API is on a server which is not yet on production yet :(

Comment: I have tried 3 legged but met the same error to 2 legged case. Can I have any advice?

Comment: contact me at cyrille at autodesk.com, because everything works on my side.

Comment: Thx for sharing the additional information - I see now, my fault not having tried this on Windows. I submit the fix this morning. Can you download the updated code, and try again and let me know if placement.json is downloaded. placement.json usually comes with a Revit file, so you know. It is a manifest file for sheets, you do not really need it, it is used by BIM360 only.